# Show/hide the top panel with a keybind?

Tags: gnome, panel, gnome-panel, disk-usage, autohide

I'm using a computer with very little screen space available. I'd like to be able to hide the top panel on a keypress while I work so I can grab a little extra room for the window I'm using. Is there something like I described? or even a hot-top where mousing over the top of the screen brings the panel back would be acceptable.

I am running Gnome 3.4 not Unity!

Answer (score 1):

found the extension to do this: Panel Settings

Comment: Can you add a bit more to this answer please? Maybe a link to the extension or a how-to get it and use it? Thanks